# How do I block this (carrier) advertisement dialog?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat

I receive this kind of messages almost every day, and I'm tired of them.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

I want to block them, but I have no idea how are they called.  I'm looking for a way to block this messages, either via an app (doesn't matter if it needs root) or programatically (if I can detect these messages, perhaps I would be able to create an app to block them).

EDIT:
The message icon is the same as the SIM Toolkit. Could this be related? As far as I know, Cell Broadcasts don't show with "OK" and "Cancel" buttons as this message.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From what I can see from [this site (In Spanish):](http://tuquejasuma.com/804/movistar-y-su-publicadad-invasiva)  this is a specific advertising service that only the `Movistar` network seems to push to phones.

The only solution I found is to Disable the "SIM Toolkit" application, `Settings > Applications > SIM Toolkit` but this may require [root](/questions/tagged/root) access to your device.
Removing SIM toolkit [according to Android Forum users](http://androidforums.com/esteem-all-things-root/635541-sim-toolkit-ahhhhhhh.html) can be removed without any issues. I would `Disable` it rather than take the nuclear deletion option personally.

From the link:

> Hasn't been on my phone in a year... no problems without it - that I'm aware of.

and

> I know for a fact that 4G works without it... has not been on my phone for the last year - and every ROM I could flash made no difference. I'm really temped to believe that SimToolKit is for Metro's various services/bloatware (where they monitor data usage - for whatever reason)

[From Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIM_Application_Toolkit)

> SIM Application Toolkit (commonly referred to as STK) is a standard of the GSM system which enables the Subscriber Identity Module (SIM) to initiate actions which can be used for various value-added services.

These so called 'value added services' are what you want to remove.

Alternatively you could contact Movistar and see if they can stop it, tell them it is crashing your device or causing you issues and ask what can be done. Depending on your contract you could move to another network also.

Comment: Well, I was trying to avoid contacting them, but I'll have to. Anyway, disabling SIM Toolkit *is* an option for me. What kind of consequences should I expect if I do so?

Comment: I don't know to be honest!I'm on the bus, I'll update when the find out!

Comment: @DanielCastro I have updated my answer now. It seems safe to remove, but obviously at your own risk. I have provided links and quotes for further details. Please do not hesitate to ask anything further and if I can help I'll add it to my answer! Thanks for the upvote!

Comment: TIGO is doing this now too.  I can't seem to disable the app, it seems broken as pressing ok/cancel does nothing but re-open their dialog

Comment: @FrankSchwieterman Why can't you disable the app? Keep in mind that you need root access to do this. Did you try with the answer from Kevin?

Comment: I don't have the problem now (in Peru, with a different Movistar SIM) and I can't find the SIM toolkit anymore so I can't followup for now.

Comment: I deleted SIM Toolkit on LG G3 D856 (dual sim), and had to reboot after this as well, otherwise com.android.phone was constantly crashing. After rebooting it seems to work so far.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting tired of those messages too, worse of all, the text was always garbled.

If you already have `Titanium Backup Pro` like I do, I simply "Froze" the SIM Tool Kit app. It disables the application and prevents the icon from appearing in your app drawer.

If you were ever to need it you can unfreeze or "Thaw" the app.

So far I've never seen the use of the STK. If I didn't have the backup app I would delete it without thinking twice.

Answer (score 2):

Go to SIM Toolkit and search for Flash services and deactivate it. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open SIM Toolkit app in your mobile.
2. Select the active Flash service
3. Click on "Deactivate" to turn it off.

The main challenge is choosing the correct service in Step 2. The name of the service differs from one network to another.

You can [find Flash service names of popular Network providers here](https://www.geekdashboard.com/stop-flash-messages-on-android/).

Disclosure: I'm the author of above linked article.