# Unknown popup message with a text input, "cancel" and "send" buttons, but without notification entry

Tags: sms, popup

Recently I received multiple popups that looks like this:

[image: IMG:]

The popup has a high priority since I can't do any other thing when the popup is displayed.  It also doesn't appear in the notification.  When I click "Cancel", the popup disappears immediately.

I'm running Android Oreo 8.1 with the latest security patch.  The message looks like an advertisement sent from the operator.  I've tried to disable all emergency alert (from *Wireless alerts* menu in Google's SMS application setting), but the message still appears.

I would like to know what kind of popup is this (doesn't look like from an app) and what would have triggered it.

Comment: This is similar to messages that displayed when we type USSD codes. Possibly its from the service provider.

Comment: Is it possible for service provider to trigger USSD in my phone without my consent?

Comment: Related: [How to prevent phone operator from opening spam popups?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/75761) and [How do I block this (carrier) advertisement dialog?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/75169)

Comment: Have you found the solution? I got this a lot from Indosat. Contacted their CS and have tried all of their advise but nothing works.

Comment: @AndrewT. This is different than usual flash SMS because it has an option to reply (with Send button).   Usually just have "Save" or "Discard" button.  I think [How can we send a flash SMS with reply option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867742/how-can-we-send-a-flash-sms-with-reply-option) is trying to send something that looks like this.

Comment: No, @ThariqNugrohotomo, I still don't know what is this.